# Finding common relationships in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table of relationships between firms and clients:

```
Relationships

Firm, Client
A, 1
C, 1
C, 2
```

In a query, I'd like to get a list of all clients that a particular firm does *not* currently have, and the number of firms in common with each client. A "firm in common" is a firm that a potential client uses that at least one of your clients also uses.

With the Relationships table as it is above, this would be the result for firm A:

```
Firm, Client, # of Firms in Common
A, 2, 1
```

So firm A has one firm in common with Client 2, since firm A's clients use one of Client 2's firms.

This is my query so far:

```
select r1.firm, r1.client, count(distinct(r2.firm)) from relationships r1
join relationships as r2 ON r1.client = r2.client
where r1.firm = 'FIRM NAME HERE'
group by r1.firm, r1.client
```

It is correctly showing the correct number of firms in common for each client, but it is only listing existing clients for that firm. I'd like instead to list clients that do *not* currently have a relationship with the firm.

I'd appreciate any help!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this type of question, create all the rows for firms and clients.  Then remove the ones that exist.  With your one table:

```
select f.firm, c.client
from (select distinct firm from relationship) f cross join
     (select distinct client from relationship) c left join
     relationship r
    on r.firm = f.firm and r.client = c.client
where r.client is null;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This successfully gets me firm and client relationships that do not currently exist. The other piece of this is returning a column showing the count of firms in common that the firm and client have (as the query in the question was doing, but it was only showing existing clients of each firm). I'm currently trying to merge my old query with this one to achieve that.